# Spring cloud : Can not get Feign client to work with consul

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to set up a simple spring cloud consul app.

I have a "distribution" service up and registered in consul (with the spring.application.name property set to "distribution")

I have an "acquisition" service that is trying to make a call to the "distribution" service using feign.

Here is my main class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RestController
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableHystrix
public class Acquisition {


    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    @Autowired
    private DistributionClient distributionClient;


    @RequestMapping("/use-feign")
    public String sendData() {
        distributionClient.sendData(new Data("Hello World"));
        return "sent";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/disco")
    public String disco() {
         List<ServiceInstance> list = discoveryClient.getInstances("distribution");
        if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
            return list.get(0).getUri().toString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Acquisition.class, args);
    }

}
```

here is my feign client

```
@FeignClient(value = "distribution")
interface DistributionClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/data", consumes = "application/json")
    void sendData(Data data);
}
```

and here is my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

When I request the "/disco" Url, the url of the "distribution" service is properly retrieved, which means that the whole discovery thing is working as expected.

But, when I request the "/use-feign" url, I get the following exception :

> com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have
>   available server for client: distribution     at
>   com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:468)
>   ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]    at
>   com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184)
>   ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]    at
>   com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180)
>   ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]    at
>   rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460)
>   ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94)
>   ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42)
>   ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]

Am I missing any configuration ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you put spring.application.name in bootstrap.yml?

Comment: yes, in the "distribution" app, I set spring.application.name: distribution and in the "acquisition" app, I set spring.application.name: acquisition. And I can see both services registered in consul

Comment: Can you share a project?

Comment: https://github.com/acouette/spring-cloud-distribution.git and https://github.com/acouette/spring-cloud-acquisition.git. Note that I am running consul on one node with "consul agent -dev -bind 127.0.0.1" and I did not set up the service health check so the services are marked as critical but it does not seems to bother the DiscoveryClient.

Comment: Ah, but it does affect `ConsulPing` which checks if it is passing health checks. Add health checks, it will probably work.

Comment: Ok that was it. Thank you for your help and all your work on spring cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[spencergibb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2730527/spencergibb) pointed out the problem : no health check endpoint was deployed. 
Just adding spring-boot-actuator to the dependencies solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had: `spring-boot (2.4.2)` with `spring-cloud 2020.0.1`, I have just added:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
</dependency>
```